# Как создать файл?

Tags: android, файлы

Как создать файл в Android? Используется код:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String mystring = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(mystring.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Выдает FileNotFoundException.
Если засунуть в try / catch, то IOException. Что делать? В интернете нашел решения, которые вызывают те же Exception. Заранее спасибо...

Answer (score 4):

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file", mystring = "hello world!";
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FILENAME).createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
fos.write(mystring.getBytes());
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Вот так можете. То есть, код создания файла таков:

```
new File(путь к файлу).createNewFile();
```

Comment: Вылетает IOException. И возникает вопрос : а путь к файлу как пишется? В моем случае я пишу /res/raw/file.txt . Где-то нашел что нужно через asset. Что делать?

Comment: @StyopkinStepan, папка `res` доступна только для чтения. Здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628058/how-to-write-a-file-in-android-to-the-raw-folder эта проблема обсуждалась